# Changing the background color of an entire scrollable html page by hovering works on firefox but not on google chrome

Tags: html, css

I want to change the background-color of an entire scrollable html page when I hover over any part of the page. However, when I try to do this on google chrome, it seems the background-color only changes for the top part of the page that can fit in the window. On firefox, this is not a problem. Any ideas on how I can fix this?

I made a very simple example that places a block 2000 pixels down from the top.

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head lang="en">
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title></title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="client.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="block"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
html:hover {
    background-color: red;
}

.block {
    background-color: black;
    position: absolute;
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    top: 2000px;
    right: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
html{
    height: 100%;
}
body {
    min-height: 100%;
}

html:hover,
body:hover{
    background-color: red;
}
```

Comment: I'm still getting the same issue. When I load the page on google chrome, the entire screen is red when I hover over it. However, I can scroll down and see that the rest of the page is white.